# Why is my vi Editor highlighting all the text?

Tags: linux, vi

All of a sudden all the text in my vi editor is highlighted.I have no idea how this happened. Please help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Type `/asdfjhanlskfh` or something similar that starts with a slash.

Chances are you have searched for a character (`/.`) and are using `vim` instead of `vi`.

Comment: Thank you that worked for me!! But I'm using vi and not vim. It's on Fedora

Comment: @Pavitar: try `vi --version` from the command line, or follow the symlinks of `\`which vi\``

Comment: Ohh yea..My vi is set as an alias for vim.thank you. +1

Answer (score 1):

This could be a variety of things. Its most likely because you are visual select mode (which you get to by pressing the 'v' key in command mode).  Try pressing Esc twice to see if that gets you out of it.  Another clue on this would be that it would say -- VISUAL -- in the status line.

If that's not it, giving us a bit more info would be in order, such as what you were doing at the time, if closing the file and reopening fixes it, etc.